# i wanted to select .main-head(1-9) and carry out a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

this is the code that i wrote:-

```
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
var sfq = ".main-head"+[i];
console.log(sfq);
$(sfq).mouseover(function(){
    $(sfq).addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
    setTimeout(function(){$(sfq).removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")},500);
})
}
```

The desired output:-

```
//$(".main-head1").mouseover(function(){
    //     $(".main-head1").addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
    //     setTimeout(function(){$(".main-head1").removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")},500);
// });
// $(".main-head2").mouseover(function(){
    //     $(".main-head2").addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
    //     setTimeout(function(){$(".main-head2").removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")},500);
// });
```

and so on...
I can understand why it doesn't work but is there a way around it?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: the value of sfq should be enclosed in double qoutes and currently it is just passing .main-head(1-9) rather than passing ".main-head(1-9)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("[class*=main-head]").mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")
  }, 500);
});
```

`class*=main-head` means that it will select all elements that has a class that contains main-head

**Demo**

```js
$("[class*=main-head]").mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.colorChangeOnMouseOver{
color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test main-head1">main-head1</div>


<div class="main-head1">main-head2</div>


<div class="main-head1">main-head3</div>
```

Comment: yeah that works thanks dude appreciate it

Comment: @utsavpathak No problem, happy to help

Comment: @utsavpathak If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yeah sorry didn’t know how to do that thanks for reminding!!

Comment: Every new user has to learn the ropes, thanks for taking the time to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert the `sfq` variable into a let variable so from inside the setTimeout, the value referred is correct.

Right now all the functions inside setTimeout will refer to the same one value of `sfq` which is `.main-head9`.

Also, `[]` no need to use this.

```
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
let sfq = ".main-head"+i;
console.log(sfq);
$(sfq).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver");
    setTimeout(function(){$(sfq).removeClass("colorChangeOnMouseOver")},500);
})
}
```

Comment: for some reason it shows this.addclass is not a function rather i used $(sfq) Thanks dude appreciate it

Comment: it should be `$(this)` or `$(sfq)` not `this`

Comment: No need for 1-9 at all, just give each `class='main-head'`.  Looping to add events is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I would also advise to use mouseenter and not mouseover, since mouseover will trigger everytime he moves the mouse on the element.